# Add Text to TextBox upon Click

Tags: javascript

The purpose of the code is when the letters from the array are clicked they should be displayed in the text box. The array is made of letters like a keyboard. I tried but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help please?

```
<html>

    <head>

    <body>
  <textarea id="Alltext"></textarea>
        <div id = "playground">


        </div>

    </body>




    <script>

        var Item = function(name){

            this.name = name;
            var div = document.createElement("div");

            div.className = "";
            div.innerHTML = name;
            this.div = div;
            this.appendTo = function (parent){
            parent.append(this.div);

            }

            this.setName = function(newName){
                this.div.innerHTML = newName;
                this.name = newName;
            } 



            this.div.addEventListener('click', function(event){


                //change the color of the item for 2 seconds
                var clickedElement = event.target;

                clickedElement.classList.add("clicked");

                window.setTimeout(function(){
                clickedElement.classList.remove("clicked");


                });


            });



        }

        var names = ["Q","W", "E", "R","T","Y", "U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L",];
        var playground = document.getElementById("playground");

        for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){

            var myItem = new Item(names[i]);
            myItem.appendTo(playground);            


            }


    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what this part of the code is all about `variable one=this;`  Doesn't look like any valid javascript I've ever seen.  Probably more issues than that, but you need to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should work:

```
<script>

    var Item = function(name){

        this.name = name;
        var div = document.createElement("div");

        div.className = "";
        div.innerHTML = name;
        this.div = div;
        this.appendTo = function (parent){
        parent.append(this.div);

        }

        this.setName = function(newName){
            this.div.innerHTML = newName;
            this.name = newName;
        } 



        this.div.addEventListener('click', function(event){

            //change the color of the item for 2 seconds
            var clickedElement = event.target;
            var value = document.getElementById('Alltext').value;
            var newValue = value+event.target.innerText;
            document.getElementById('Alltext').value=newValue;

            clickedElement.classList.add("clicked");

            window.setTimeout(function(){
            clickedElement.classList.remove("clicked");


            }, 2000);


        });



    }

    var names = ["Q","W", "E", "R","T","Y", "U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L",];
    var playground = document.getElementById("playground");

    for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){

        var myItem = new Item(names[i]);
        myItem.appendTo(playground);            


        }


</script>
```

I added timeout and required code to add value to the textarea.

setTimeout needs to specify how long you want to delay the function `window.setTimeout(function(){},2000); //2000 means 2 seconds delay`

Comment: @Umar let me know if it there was any issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think your `<textarea>` should be placed in `<body>` tag ... may be your code is not working due to other issues but this should have to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is likely with the `this` references in the `setTimeout`, which is equal to the window in that case (or `undefined` in strict mode), rather than the object you're expecting it to be.

`variable one=this;` is not correctly declared.

`Alltext` should be quoted in a `"`; otherwise, it's attempting to referenced a variable with that name that doesn't exist.

There are a number of issues with this code of that nature. I highly recommend opening the page in question in your browser and examining the code in the Devtools, which should show you most of these errors in advance. From there, you can work you way through the sections of code that aren't working the way you expect.

Comment: I have removed the whole set of code,  That I typed to add text in to text area , Can you show me how do it ? Thanks